# List of custom environments

Tags: table-of-contents, environments, tcolorbox

I have defined a custom environment `m` and would like to create a list of all appearances of this environment in the whole document (similar to a table of contents or list of figures/tables). This list should reference the environments similarly as the `\reqref` command defined below: showing the value of the counter `mcounter` and the (short) text provided to the environment.

Here is my baseline code (minimum working example). Any help is appreciated!

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 

\definecolor{lightgoldenrodyellow2}{rgb}{0.99, 0.99, 0.93}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=subsection]{m2}[1]{
    colback=lightgoldenrodyellow2,
    boxrule=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt, % vertical padding
    breakable,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    borderline west={4pt}{0pt}{darkgray},
    #1
}

\newcommand{\reqref}[1]{\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\textref}[1]{\ref{t@#1}}

\newcounter{mcounter}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{m}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{mcounter}%
    \begin{m2}{}\label{#1}
    \def\@currentlabel{\BODY}\label{t@#1}
    \textbf{M \themcounter:} \BODY
    \end{m2}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{m}{label1}
Content1
\end{m}

\begin{m}{label2}
Content2
\end{m}

\reqref{label1}
\textref{label1}

\end{document}
```